# jQuery: CSS Display block not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a simple dropdown menu, this is my code so far:
**HTML**

```
<div id="menuBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="" class="activate">item 1</a>
           <ul class="subs" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="">Sub 1 </a>
                <a href="">Sub 2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="" class="activate">item 1</a>
           <ul class="subs" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="">Sub 1 </a>
                <a href="">Sub 2 </a>
            </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery(".activate").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.subs').css("display", "block");
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).find('.subs').css("display", "none");
});
```

When I try it on my site nothing happens, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please make JSFiddle for better understanding

Comment: fix this.. href="class="activate"" should be href="" class="activate"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You currently have no elements with an `.activate` class because your HTML is messed up. Change:

```
<a href="class="activate"">item 1</a>
```

To:

```
<a class="activate">item 1</a>
```

Once you've fixed that, you're still going to have problems as `.subs` isn't a descendant of `.activate`. You'll need to use [**jQuery's `next()` method**](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to select the `.subs` element instead:

```
jQuery(".activate").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).next('.subs').css("display", "block");
}), function(){
    jQuery(this).next('.subs').css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: It was correct in my code, just copied it wrong here. And your solution worked, I will accept it when I can

Comment: @user3164891 please see the part of my answer about fixing your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try

### HTML

```
<div id="menuBox">
    <ul>
        <li>
           <a href="" class="activate">item 1</a>
           <ul class="subs" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="">Sub 1 </a>
                <a href="">Sub 2 </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
           <a href="" class="activate">item 1</a>
           <ul class="subs" style="display: none;">
            <li>
                <a href="">Sub 1 </a>
                <a href="">Sub 2 </a>
            </li>
           </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

### JS

```
jQuery(".activate").hover(function(){
    jQuery(this).next('.subs').show();
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).next('.subs').hide();
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/429sdLoy/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="class="activate"">item 1</a>
```

Corrected above line as:

```
<p class="activate" style="cursor:pointer;">item 1</p>
```